# Something like forEach in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, sum, db2

So i need to make a query that displays how many times each item has been sold, i have two tables that look something like this

```
Products
+-----------+-------+-----------+
| productID | price | inventory |
+-----------+-------+-----------+
| 31f9d     | 21    | 109       |
| M21xZ     | 80    | 87        |
| 56JmZ     | 35    | 48        |
+-----------+-------+-----------+

orderDetails
+---------+-------+----------+
| orderId | item  | Quantity |
+---------+-------+----------+
| 1       | 31f9d | 2        |
| 2       | 31f9d | 5        |
| 2       | 56JmZ | 3        |
+---------+-------+----------+
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a very basic aggregate query SQL. What did you try that did not work?

Comment: In programming languages you tell the computer how to do things, e.g. loop through data with ForEach. SQL is not a programming language, but a fourth generation query language. You just tell the computer what to do not how to do it. You don't say "loop though my data", but "give me the products combined with their order amounts". It's up to the DBMS to decide how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the number of sales per product, you can aggregate the details table:

```
select item, count(*) as cnt_sales, sum(quantity) as sum_quantity
from orderdetails
group by item
```

If you want the details of each products too, then you can join.

```
select p.*, d.cnt_sales, d.sum_quantity
from products p
left join (
    select item, count(*) as cnt_sales, sum(quantity) as sum_quantity
    from orderdetails
    group by item
) d on d.item = p.productid
```

The `left join` allows products without any sale; it will bring `null` values in columns `cnt_sales`  and `sum_quantity` in the resultset.

Comment: Thank you! Used the other answer but also learned a lot from this one!

Answer (score 1):

Join both tables together, then simply group by itemId:

```
select p.productID, sum(o.Quantity) from Products p 
    left join orderDetails o on p.productID = o.item 
group by p.productID
```

Comment: You are joining **tables** by the way. The **database** is the whole thing containing all the tables.

Comment: Not a native speaker heh, fixed :)

Comment: Thank you! this is exactly what i was looking for, learned a lot, thanks again!